# How to display user json data base on href id?

Tags: php, json

Ihave Json data stored in my main local folder and I want to display user data into another page "view.php" if i-click **View User Data** href="view.php?id=1" automatically user id=1 is displayed in view.php file.

data.json

```
{
    "UserData": [

    {
        "id": "1",
        "fname": "Joey",
        "lname": "Tulang",
        "age": "29",
        "gender": "Male"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "fname": "Angelica",
        "lname": "Bacle",
        "age": "20",
        "gender": "Female"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "fname": "Mj",
        "lname": "King",
        "age": "21",
        "gender": "male"
    }       

    ]   
}
```

index.php

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents("data.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$output = "<ul>";

  foreach ( $json['UserData'] as $display ) {

    $output .="<li>" .$display['fname']. " <a href='view.php?".$display['id']."'>View User Data</a></li> </br>";

  }

  $output .= "</ul>";

  echo $output;
```

Output:

https://ibb.co/MCfgWVZ

view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>View User Data</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Display User Data Here -->

    <p>First Name: </p>
    <p>Last Name: </p>
    <p>Age: </p>
    <p>Gender: </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**index.php**

Your forgetting the `id` param and just setting the number.

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents("data.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$output = "<ul>";

foreach ( $json['UserData'] as $display ) {
  $output .="<li>" .$display['fname']. " <a href='view.php?id=".$display['id']."'>View User Data</a></li> </br>";
}

$output .= "</ul>";

echo $output;
```

**view.php**

Use `$_GET['id']` to query your json:

```
<?php
$jsondata = file_get_contents("data.json");
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);

$key = array_search((int) $_GET['id'], array_column($json['UserData'], 'id'));

// if $key false, was not found, presume it was...

$user = $json['UserData'][$key];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>View User Data</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Display User Data Here -->

    <p>First Name: <?= $user['fname'] ?></p>
    <p>Last Name: <?= $user['lname'] ?></p>
    <p>Age: <?= $user['age'] ?></p>
    <p>Gender: <?= $user['gender'] ?></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i forgot to mention, is better to use a database.

Comment: np, happy coding

Comment: Hi Lawrence can you help me with how to solve this? sorry I'm a newbie in programming https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62270632/how-to-loop-or-display-json-data-using-php